# apiblueprint parameters that aren't in url

Tags: parameters, apiblueprint

I'm just curious if there is a way to use parameters without them being in the url just so the person looking at the documentation knows what needs to be input to get the action to actually occur. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To display parameters description in the middle column of the Apiary documentation you need to describe them on the resource level (under a resource, not under an action).

Like so:

```
# Resource [/r{?a,b}]
+ Parameters
    + a - this parameter means X
    + b - this parameter means Y

## Action [GET]
+ Response 200
```